# Virtual ruby - No such file or directory -- main.rb (LoadError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, user-interface

I have installed visual ruby in windows7. It got installed properly. But
when i start the application, 'visual ruby project root' opens but no
folders are displayed there, so i chose select folder and selected a
example project and clicked open. Now the visual ruby application got
opened and the list of example projects got displayed in the left pan.
If i select any of the project and click run am getting the following
error.

```
C:/Users/abhiram/visualruby/examples$ ruby main.rb
ruby: No such file or directory -- main.rb (LoadError)
```

I dono how to fix it. Could any one help me out of this.

Comment: You must have accidentally deleted your main.rb file.

Answer (score 1):

Look in the menus for "Project Settings."  There is a command line that shows the program that will run when you press the "run" button.  The default is "ruby main.rb"  It will simply execute that command when the "run" button is pressed.  http://visualruby.net